# What is meaning of the term Whitelisting in antivirus?

Tags: virus, antivirus, protection

How exactly does whitelisting work and what does it mean in terms of antivirus software?

Answer (score 3):

Whitelisting is when the antivirus company explicitly marks a file signature as safe. Sometimes antivirus programs incorrectly identifies a file or program as being malicious, which can prevent the program from working. The computer user or developer can then contact the antivirus company and ask that the file signature be marked as safe. The the file will no longer be detected as malicious allowing it to be used again.

Often for programs the Code Signing Certificate signature of the creator is marked as trusted instead. This way all future programs signed by the company will be ignored by the antivirus software.

Comment: `all future programs signed by the company will be ignored by the antivirus software.`  My eye rolls.   Citation needed.

Comment: So are you going to build both whitelist and black list to migitate stolen certificate? 
http://www.pcworld.com/article/3048417/malware-authors-quickly-adopt-sha-2-through-stolen-code-signing-certificates.html

Comment: @mootmoot Citation: I manage the deployment of several software products that have been whitelisted by my companies code signing to prevent false av detection of future versions. This saves an incredible amount of time and money getting the individual versions whitelisted. Here is another example, Microsoft gives EV signed programs a free pass through SmartScreen and Defender https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2012/08/14/microsoft-smartscreen-extended-validation-ev-code-signing-certificates/.

Comment: Prior to signing the programs do not pass VirusTotal scans, post signing they do.

Comment: @mootmoot and yes, most antivirus programs include a list of revoked code signing certificates.

Comment: Extended Validtion(EV) inherit the some weakness as domain validation. Unscrupulous entities may get EV from CA and distributed signed software that contains stealth code that download unwanted software/malware. So base on whitelist and automatic revoke is not good enough. IMHO, perhaps Microsoft defender doing it(trust the EV for no reason) , but I doubt major antivirus take this risky path.

Answer (score 0):

Whitelisting is just a methodology. The methodology can be applied in many ways.

I will show two simple example, at the front end and backend.

So let's talk about user front end : 
Here, Whitelisting is about trusting files or SSL certificates, to make sure they are from valid entities. However, certificate itself can be point of attack ,e.g. signature can be stolen and malware can be signed with the stolen signature.  So at the end, you might trusting a malware before the root certificate found out (which mostly reported by antivirus company or other security expert) and revoke it.
Most Antivirus use the certificate to prevent false positive, but it may still flag file/url with valid certificate if the detection engine found strange content in a file/url.

While at the backend, antivirus company build process that check millions of prominent software file to make sure no false positives are reported to render user system useless. This is how antivirus doesn't flag at least ~500 version of Microsoft svchost.exe(various Microsoft security fix and updates) as virus.

Just check the above example, you will notice whitelisting has inherited weakness and usability complexity. It can never be used as the only security measurement to prevent attack/exploit.  Building a application that only allow whitelist to run means you will going to break things VERY FAST. On the other hand, putting millions of whitelist files not going to help your business : the logistic to maintain and push the file to user end is costly.

If anyone are so naive to believe whitelisting security is a valid business, investor investing on those business will see their money vaporised in no time.

This is why prominent antivirus rarely debunk the whitelisting myth , which is overrated by some "security-expert" and media journalist that don't understand the issues.